# jQuery: if my css visibility:hidden, how can i appear my elements?

Tags: jquery, visibility, opacity

in my css i've set some elements visibiliy:hidden, how can I show them?

I've done it before with opacity, but i've some bug in IE:

```
var i = 0;
$mySelection.each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i * 100) + ($mySelection.length)).animate(
        { opacity: "1"},
        {queue:true, duration:1000, easing:"quartEaseIn"}
    ); 
})
```

How can i do if I want controll visibility with jQuery instead of opacity?
thank you

Comment: Can you gives us an update on whether you have what you need? If not, could you give us more details?

Answer (score 41):

```
$(":hidden").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `visibility: hidden`, use `display:none`, then if you want to fade in your hidden element use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).  For example:

```
$("div:hidden").fadeIn("slow");
```

**Edit:** Given that you want to use visibility, try this:

```
var i = 0;
$mySelection.each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i * 100) + ($mySelection.length)).css(
        { 'opacity': '0', 'visibility': 'visible'}).animate(
            { opacity: "1"},
            {queue:true, duration:1000, easing:"quartEaseIn"});
});
```

Comment: Why should he switch to `display`? `visibility` behaves totally different.

Comment: I presented it as an alternative to simplify the animation. Realise that `display: none` removes the element from view completely rather than just hiding it.

Comment: visibility use (topic of the question) is with diferent purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to change the CSS visibility attribute with Jquery. Where the element1 on hover will change visibility of element2.

Did two different script for same element to give a mouseover-mouseleave effect.

```
 <script>$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".element1").mouseover(function(){
     $(".element2").css("visibility","visible");
 });
```

});

```
         <script>$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".element1").mouseleave (function(){
     $(".element2").css("visibility","hidden");
 });
```

});

Note.- That Element2 the one thats CSS is being affected, originally is hidden. so when mouse is over Element1, Element2 shows up. When mouse leaves element1, Element2 Hides again. Hope it helps

-Expiriance of this code reaserching and mixing some other codes from users in stack overflow

Answer (score -3):

```
$(':hidden').show();
```

I hope this helps and I hope I understood your question :) http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
$mySelection.show();
```

Comment: Doesn't work;  jQuery show() sets 'display' CSS property, doesn't affect 'visibility'.